# How return MTOM in Spring BOOT WS

Tags: spring-boot, soap, spring-ws, mtom

I have a problem with my Spring Boot Soap Server, im using Spring WS, i have to return my files in attachments,  i return a Datahandler to the listtype created by Jaxb, but i see in the response in soap ui, attachments 0, and return me the files in base64.
I dont know how to do this.
Can you help me.
Thanks so much.

My Configuration Bean is:

```
@Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/services/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "students")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema countriesSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("StudentPort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws/services/test");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://www.example.org/demo/");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(countriesSchema);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("getDemo", "http://www.example.org/demo/getDemoRequest");
        wsdl11Definition.setSoapActions(props);

        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema countriesSchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("/it/xsd/demo.xsd"));
    }
```

My endpoint have only these annotations:

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getDemoRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
```

In my demo.xsd, i setted the fileType in

```
<element name="fileType" type="base64Binary" maxOccurs="unbounded" xmime:expectedContentTypes="application/octet-stream">
```

I havent xml configuration for now, i would like dont use any xml if it is not necessary in perfect style of Spring Boot.

Thanks so much.

**UP**:
My code to try enable MTOM.

```
  import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller;
    import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurerAdapter;
    import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.MarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor;
    import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.MethodArgumentResolver;

    import java.util.List;

    @Configuration
public class MTOMEnable extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<MethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(methodProcessor());
    }

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(GetStudentsResponse.class);
        marshaller.setMtomEnabled(true);
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public MarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor methodProcessor() {
        return new MarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor(marshaller());
    }
}
```

**POM**

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- SOAP DEPENDENCIES-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal</groupId>
            <artifactId>resolver</artifactId>
            <version>20050927</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0.jre8</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b180830.0438</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version> <!-- makesure you put a correct version here -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204440/discussion-on-question-by-toriga-how-return-mtom-in-spring-boot-ws).

Comment: Hi @Toriga did you manage to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter bean adds our MTOM-enabled JAXB marshaller/unmarshaller to the END of the handlers' list.  The trick is to override the DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter bean and put them FIRST.  This way you don't even need to override the addArgumentResolvers().

The following is Kotlin but should be easy enough to convert to plain Java.

```
@Bean
override fun defaultMethodEndpointAdapter() = object: DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter() {
    override fun initDefaultStrategies() {
        super.initDefaultStrategies()
        methodArgumentResolvers.add(0, methodProcessor()) // needs to be FIRST in list
        methodReturnValueHandlers.add(0, methodProcessor()) // needs to be FIRST in list
    }
}
```

You also need to make sure the relevant @RequestPayload and return params are JAXBELement<...>