# Spring WS server MTOM is empty

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-ws

I am trying to create a wS where the user submits one or more files as MTOM messages, but the content of this files seems to be empty in the endpoint.

This is my endpoint where I save the submitted files.

```java
@Endpoint
public class EndPointAlt {
    

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = "http://example.com/custom", localPart = "uploadFilesRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public UploadFilesResponse altaFile(@RequestPayload final UploadFilesRequest request) {
        List<FileObject> files = request.getName().getFiles();
        for (FileObject fileObject : files) {
            String name = fileObject.getName();
            byte[] content = fileObject.getContent();
            try {
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(FILES_PATH + name));
                os.write(content);
                os.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // ....
    }
}
```

In this interceptor I can see the actual content of the request:

```java
@Component
public class CustomInterceptor implements SmartEndpointInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bosRequest = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        messageContext.getRequest().writeTo(bosRequest);
        logger.info("#############################################");
        logger.info(bosRequest.toString("UTF-8"));
        logger.info("#############################################");
        bosRequest.close();
        return true;
    }
//...
}
```

And finally this is my configuration file of the WS:

```java
//@EnableWs
//@SpringBootConfiguration
//@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.demo"})
@Configuration
public class CustomApplicationContext extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        logger.info("Marshaller");
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath("com.example.demo.infraestructure.vendor.custom");
        Map<String, Object> propertiesMap = new HashMap<>();
        propertiesMap.put(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        propertiesMap.put(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        marshaller.setMtomEnabled(true);
        marshaller.setMarshallerProperties(propertiesMap);
        return marshaller;
    }
    @Bean
    public MarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor methodProcessor() {
        logger.info("MarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor");
        return new MarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor(marshaller());
    }

    // @Override
    // public void addArgumentResolvers(List<MethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
    //     argumentResolvers.add(methodProcessor());
    // }

    // I have replaced the previous method with:
    @Bean
    DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter endpointAdapter(MarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor methodProcessor) {
        DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter adapter = new DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter();
        adapter.setMethodArgumentResolvers(Collections.singletonList(methodProcessor));
        adapter.setMethodReturnValueHandlers(Collections.singletonList(methodProcessor));
        return adapter;
    }

  // In case this is needed here is the WSDL method signature too:
  //  @Bean(name = "endpoint2")
  //  public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(@Qualifier("customSchema") XsdSchema customSchema) {
}
```

I am trying to test the service with SOAP-UI and this is how the request is configured:[image: SOAP UI Configuration]

If I configure the request as Enable MTOM and Force MTOM to false the WS receives the content of the file and I can save it, but I want to actually use MTOM as attachment.

--
This is the request SOAP UI is generating:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/ws HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; start="<rootpart@soapui.org>"; start-info="text/xml"; boundary="----=_Part_6_873425781.1649702359473"
SOAPAction: ""
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Length: 181749
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/16.0.1)
```

And this is the xsd file I use in order to generate the classes with JAXB:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tns="http://example.com/custom"
    xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime"
    targetNamespace="http://example.com/custom"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <!-- Types -->
    <xs:complexType name="fileList">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="files" type="tns:fileObject"
                maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="fileObject">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Content" type="xs:base64Binary" />
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- Requests and responses -->
    <xs:element name="uploadFilesRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="tns:fileList" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="uploadFilesResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="response" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: The problem is your interceptor. You are reading the request as you can only read the request once, there is nothing left for the endpoint to process.

Comment: I thought so too, but I have removed it and I still have no content

Comment: Actually I was trying to follow one answer that you did some time ago, but I couldn't get it right: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59318914

Comment: Is the file actually being send as MTOM? Did you use JAXB to generate your XML objects?

Comment: I have updated the post in order to include the raw request that I am generating and the xsd file that I use to generate java classes with JAXB.

Comment: I don't really get this comment of yours *If I configure the request as Enable MTOM and Force MTOM to false the WS receives the content of the file and I can save it, but I want to actually use MTOM as attachment.* . Which is basically what it does? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Sorry I didn't express well. What I was trying to say was: if I send the request with a PDF as attachment using MTOM , the PDF in the server will be empty, whereas if I send the request with the PDF as inline file attachment the content will be present in the server. I am trying to send requests with attachments using MTOM, in order to do so, do I need to check both options: Enable MTOM and Force MTOM? Or If I just enable MTOM the attachment will be sent using MTOM?

Comment: EnableMTOM should be enough in SoapUI. Not sure if there is a limit on the filesize (if smaller then something it will be inlined).

Comment: I made the following changes in WsConfigurerAdapter: 1. I have replaced these annotations: `@EnableWs, @SpringBootConfiguration and @ComponentScan` with `@Configuration`. 2. I replaced `@Override  public void addArgumentResolvers` with a bean `@Bean DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter endpointAdapter` where I set `setMethodArgumentResolvers and setMethodReturnValueHandlers` . With these changes seems to be working. If its ok with you I will update the post with these changes, because I am probably doing something terrible wrong.